# Scatter plot without x-axis

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to visualize some data and have built a scatter plot with this code -

```
sns.regplot(y="Calls", x="clientid", data=Drop)
```

This is the output -

[image]

I don't want it to consider the x-axis. I just want to see how the data lie w.r.t y-axis. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You are performing a fit with `regplot`. If there is no x data, no fit can be produced. Can you explain more in detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want to find groups in data. As you can see, 0-5 looks like 1 group. 5-12 looks like another group. 13-20 also look like they can form a group.

Comment: I don't feel that answers my question. What is the reason to use a `regplot` here? What do you want to fit if only a single variable is present?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't want to fit anything. I just want a scatter plot of the y-axis.

Comment: A scatter plot is done via `plt.scatter`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did this - `plt.scatter(y="Calls", x="clientid", data=Drop)
` and it still gives me numbers on the x-axis. I want it to ignore the x-axis.

Comment: Maybe you want `plt.scatter(y="Calls", x=numpy.ones(len(Drop)), data=Drop)`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That's exactly what I needed. How do I avoid it from showing the x-axis all together.

Comment: You can't do this with a scatterplot because an "x" axis a requirement. Perhaps you want a [stripplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)?

Comment: @iayork That is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to move the dots closer to the y axis, so I can clearly see their values. Right now they are in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @iayork suggested, you can see the distribution of your points with a [`striplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html?highlight=strip#seaborn.stripplot) or a [`swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarm#seaborn.swarmplot) (you could also combine them with a [`violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html?highlight=violin#seaborn.violinplot)). If you need to move the points closer to the y-axis, you can simply adjust the size of the figure so that the width is small compared to the height (here i'm doing 2 subplots on a 4x5 in figure, which means that each plot is roughly 2x5 in).

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(4,5))
sns.stripplot(d, orient='vert', ax=ax1)
sns.swarmplot(d, orient='vert', ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

However, I'm going to suggest that maybe you want to use [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html?highlight=distplot#seaborn.distplot) instead. This function is specifically created to show the distribution of you data. Here i'm plotting the KDE of the data, as well as the "rugplot", which shows the position of the points along the y-axis:

```
fig = plt.figure()
sns.distplot(d, kde=True, vertical=True, rug=True, hist=False, kde_kws=dict(shade=True), rug_kws=dict(lw=2, color='orange'))
```

[image]